# can't pass variable on javascript, it's passing the html element instead of the referenced variable?

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code:

```
function newTodo() {
  const text = prompt('What needs to be done?').trim();
  if (!!text) {
    id += 1;
    const todoId = 'todo' + id;
    // checkbox
    const todoCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
    todoCheckbox.type = 'checkbox';
    todoCheckbox.id = todoId;
    todoCheckbox.classname = classNames.TODO_CHECKBOX;
    todoCheckbox.setAttribute('onclick', `handleCheck(${todoId})`);
   ...
  } else {
    alert('Please enter a valid todo');
  }
}

function handleCheck(todoId) {
  console.log('checked!', todoId);
}
```

but handleClick is logging the html element the function is attached to:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="todo2" onclick="handleCheck(todo2)">
```

I wanted to log the id only, so i am expecting it to be:

```
todo2
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `handleClick` you mean `handleCheck` ?

Comment: not sure what you are passing to your function is a string. try to enclose it in single quotes `<input type="checkbox" id="todo2" onclick="handleCheck('todo2')">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler:

```
onclick="handleCheck(todo2)"
```

attempts to reference a global variable named "todo2" and pass it to the `handleCheck` function. Because (confusingly) element IDs are automatically added to the global object, this results in the element you just created being passed to the function.

Surround the `todoId` in quotes instead, to ensure it gets passed as a string:

```
todoCheckbox.setAttribute('onclick', `handleCheck('${todoId}')`);
```

But, it would be significantly more elegant to add the handler properly using Javascript instead of an inline HTML attribute:

```
todoCheckbox.onclick = () => handleCheck(todoId);
```

Dynamic IDs are a code smell, though - they're rarely necessary. If you need data unique for each element, you might consider using `data-` attributes, or a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `<input type="checkbox" id="todo2" onchange="handleCheck(todo2)">`